# Android Resources$NotFoundException on a specific language

Tags: android, android-resources

So basically, I have an app which has thousands of downloads and some users (around 200) see their app crashing on an activity with this exception
`android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
 at android.content.res.Resources.getStringArray (Resources.java:1391)`

So here is where the code crash (at the second line) :

```
int arrayId = getResources().getIdentifier(ct, "array", view.getContext().getPackageName());
String[] ctOp = getResources().getStringArray(arrayId);
```

The array I retrieve has this `tools:ignore="MissingTranslation"` and it is only in values folder (nothing in values-XX for example).

Another thing is that all people who contacted me about this crash come from Turkey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, I was doing this :

```
ct = ct.toLowerCase();
```

And apparently in Turkish there is a bug if you do it this way so you need to do it like that :

```
ct = ct.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Same for `toUpperCase`

[For more information about this bug, click here](http://mattryall.net/blog/2009/02/the-infamous-turkish-locale-bug)